# iphone/ipad web app mode - allow cross sub domain links to open in app mode

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

I have web app using this code in the head to allow iOS devices to open it in app mode (no safari header/footer)

This is my code.

*Source taken from http://html5boilerplate.com/*

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="">

<script>
    (function (a, b, c) {
        if (c in b && b[c]) {
            var d, e = a.location,
                f = /^(a|html)$/i;

            a.addEventListener("click", function (a) {
                d = a.target;

                while (!f.test(d.nodeName)) d = d.parentNode && !$(noddy).hasClass('lightbox');
                "href" in d && (d.href.indexOf("http") || ~d.href.indexOf(e.host)) && (a.preventDefault(), e.href = d.href)

            }, !1)
        }
    })
    (document, window.navigator, "standalone")
</script>
```

**MY QUESTION**

This web app I created is a network wordpress website using wild card sub domain mapping.

So for example my wordpress url's is like this...

- **one.wordpress-network.com**
- **two.wordpress-network.com**
- **three.wordpress-network.com**
- **four.wordpress-network.com**

Ok my problem lies when I am on **one.wordpress-network.com** and theres a link in my web app that links to **two.wordpress-network.com**

If I click on this link then it does nothing. How can I ammend the script above to allow sub domains for my **wordpress-network.com** to be accessed in iOS web-app mode.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or code.
Josh